# In .NET, is a data-centric architectural approach still the default? If not, what has replaced it?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

When last involved in .NET, Microsoft advocated an architectural approach where one programmed against a representation of the database in code - datasets, datatables etc. This suited their auto-generated code by tools based approach. They never advocated a rich object domain model as the basis for your architecture.

Has this position changed?  Is a rich domain model architectural approach now advocated or supported by Microsoft, especially as a result of introducing Entity Framework, or is a data-centric approach still advocated?

Comment: There is no DataTable in .NET Core 1.0. It doesn't mean you can't hack your own, but it seems pretty clear in what direction this is going.

Comment: @KooKiz So, the question remains.  In a non-functional application what approach is now advocated? Still a transaction script controller with all logic working against some representation of the database? Or one working against an object domain model containing the logic? Or one working against something else?

Comment: I don't think that MS is really advocating any particular style.  They have examples of using CQRS and Event-Sourcing if memory serves.  However, proper object-orientation / rich domain modeling is quite an art and it is difficult to get right and some of their advocates showing how to do, for instance, domain-driven design seem to end up with rather anemic models.  Perhaps the samples are too simplistic.  In any event, I think the *perception* of a data-centric MS is something they are going to find difficult to shake.  They also focus more on open-source nowadays but that ain't helping much.

Comment: @Eben many thanks. I found your comment particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is now the recommended data access solution as opposed to ADO.NET. F# has type providers and allows designing domain specific languages. This embraces information rich programming.

Now .NET Core is moving away from tooling and auto-generated approaches. It is cross-platform, agile and focused on what open source communities doing for years.

To summarize, .NET is now not revolving around database and tools.

Comment: Nirvin, many thanks. In a non-functional application what approach is now advocated?  Still a transaction script controller with all logic working against some representation of the database?  Or one working against an object domain model containing the logic?  Or one working against something else?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this [MSDN "Patterns and Practices" series book](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx) from 2012, they have been recommending a rich domain model approach for quite a while.

Not that this is an exclusive recommendation - Microsoft basically moved to a less opinionated, right-tool-for-the-right-job speech about pretty much everything they provide, and the data-centric tools are still there. Regardless, it would be suicidal of them to lag behind everyone else and still recommend a data first, code-generation based only approach these days.

[Edit]
You should note that CQRS and/or Event Sourcing are not exclusive of a rich domain model, quite the opposite. CQRS commands trigger rich domain logic in entities, which then emit (rich) domain events. It's precisely what the book describes. Don't be fooled by the title.

Comment: Thanks guillaume. The link you provide doesn't point to a rich domain model approach.  CQRS and Event Sourcing is hardly that.  Its an event driven approach for writes, and a data-centric approach for reads.  Mind your, their prescriptive practice is only on the "exploring" level.  Frankly, I'm stunned.

Comment: @JonBadda the article series is four years old. I guess there is no problem with it being at the exploring level

Comment: @JonBadda Both CQRS and Event Sourcing came from the Domain Driven Design sphere which is obviously *the* big rich domain approach out there. Event Sourcing events reflect by themselves a rich domain model.

Comment: Also, did you read the book ? [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591570#inside-the-write-model) it is obvious that we're dealing with a rich domain model. See my edit.

Comment: Besides, 376 pages of guidance, practical application on a real case and the accompanying code base is a little deep to be called "exploring level" in my book.

Comment: @guillaume I did read the book.  I even evaluated a degree project based on it.

No it is not obvious at all.  The page you link to contains a small listing of domain concept definitions, then the rest of the web page is about technology and non-functional requirements.  No rich interactions between domain concepts, no constraints.  I can only point to Fowler's definition to convey my definition of a Domain Model.  Yours obviously differs.

Comment: From Fowler's PoEAA : `Domain Model - An object model of the domain that incorporates both behaviour and data`. Look at the `MakeReservation()` method on that page. It's a very good example of domain logic implemented right in the aggregate. The reverse would mean that all logic is in external transaction scripts and the business model only has getters and setters. It is not the case.

Comment: Adding a method to an object does not make a domain model. Or more accurately 2 in your case - command and query models.  You have reduced a complex domain to simply controllers calling independent silos of logic that cannot directly communicate with each other.  From PoEAA - "A Domain Model creates a web of _interconnected_ objects".  Your silos might as well be transaction scripts or functions in a functional language.  No wonder CQRS and ES have such functional advocates in Greg Young and Vaughn Vernon. The logic is perverse, we are using an "Aggregate", so we therefore have a domain model!

Comment: You're right, an aggregate alone doesn't make a rich domain model. Having methods that reflect the domain's ubiquitous language and contain domain logic does. If there has to be a web of interconnected domain objects, it will be a multiple-entity aggregate. But sometimes there isn't such a web - sometimes an aggregate is more like a standalone state machine, just like in the book example. It doesn't mean the aggregate next door will be likewise. Also, emitting and subscribing to events can be seen as one way of being interconnected.